# Chrome: How to get details of External Extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

An extension (id = "AAAAAA") now listen messages from external extension by using

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function(mess, sender, sendRes) { ... });
```

When another extension (id = "XXXXXXX", name = "FooBar") send message to "AAAAAAA" by using

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage("AAAAAA", {})
```

of course "AAAAAA" can receive this.

But, is there any way to get "XXXXXX"'s name ("FooBar") from `sender.id` ("XXXXXX"), just like `chrome.app.getDetail()` returns its own detail?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but only if you have a heavy-handed `"management"` permission.

Then you have access to [`chrome.management` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management), among other things providing [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-get):

```
chrome.management.get(sender.id, function(details){
  console.log(details.name);
});
```

Beware though, this is probably overkill. This permission allows you to manipulate other extensions and apps, and as such will trigger a [permission warning](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings).